# Passing NuGet 'Pack' arguments in Azure DevOps Build Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package, azure-pipelines

In my Azure DevOps Build pipeline, I have added a NuGet task of *pack* command type (version 2.*).

I am trying to pass the `-Exclude ***.tt` argument so that it excludes these files when referenced from another projects. However, in the generated NuGet package, those .tt files are appearing in the Content folder.

The command written in the log of the host is:

```
nuget.exe pack PROJECTNAME.csproj -NonInteractive -OutputDirectory SOME_OUTPUTPATH -Properties "Configuration=release;\"-Exclude ***.tt\"" -Verbosity Detailed
```

As you see, exclude is not part of the properties but should be as a separate `-Exclude` argument.

Any idea how may I achieve this? Many thanks!

Added a screenshot and YAML:

[image]

```
steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet pack'
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: ProjectName.csproj
    buildProperties: '-Exclude ***.tt'
```

Comment: Can you share your nuget task? (yaml or screenshot)

Comment: Edited the original post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `-Exclude` with `nuget pack .csproj` you need to give the full path the excluded file. but there is another issue here, Azure DevOps append the `-Exclude` to the `-Properties` and it is ignore the exlucding so we need to add the `-Exclude` in another way, how? in NuGet `custom` command:

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: custom
    arguments: 'pack "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Path\To\.csproj" -Exclude "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Path\to\*.tt"'
```

Here a log from the regular `-Exclude` as you tried, you can see that the nuget pack my `.exe` file:

[image]

And here a log after I make the custom command, there is no `.exe`:

[image]

My task is:

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: custom
    arguments: 'pack "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestVars\TestVars\TestVars.csproj" -Exclude "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestVars\TestVars\bin\Debug\*.exe"'
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a great approach. Will take into consideration the `custom` field during packing.

Answer (score 3):

> Passing NuGet 'Pack' arguments in Azure DevOps Build Pipeline

You could not use the argument `-Exclude` in this way. That because this argument is used for `.nuspec` not `.csproj`, `-Exclude` is not the Property in the project file, so we could not use it with `.csproj`.

When you check the nuget document [nuget pack command (NuGet CLI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-pack), you can see the  following example:

```
nuget pack Package.nuspec -exclude "*.exe" -exclude "*.bat"
```

If you want to exclude `.tt` files with project file `.csproj`, you have to go to your project file to excluded this type of file, like:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="**.tt">
      <Pack>False</Pack>
      <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Test.txt</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    ...
  </ItemGroup>
```

If you do not want to modify the source file, you can create the `.nuspec` file, then pack the `.nuspec` file with argument `-Exclude`.

For example, I create following `.nuspec`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyTestCore</id>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
    <authors>TestContentFile</authors>
    <owners>TestContentFile</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package Description</description>
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="any/any/Data.xml" buildAction="content" flatten="true" copyToOutput="true"/>
      <files include="any/any/Test.cs" buildAction="content" flatten="true" copyToOutput="true"/>
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>

  <files>
    <file src="contentFiles/any/any/Data.xml" target="contentFiles/any/any/Data.xml" />
    <file src="contentFiles/any/any/Test.cs" target="contentFiles/any/any/Test.cs" />
  </files>
</package>
```

If I pack this .nuspec file with argument `-Exclude "**\*.cs"`:

[image]

Then we could to know, the `.cs` is excluded in the package.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I went to my C# project and changed the Build Action of the Context.tt files (related to .edmx) to None. That way, all those files where not included after after packing.

Comment: I have tried to change Build Action to None but I get an exception:
MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource.

Answer (score 0):

It solved for me in Visual Studio 2015:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="**.tt">
        <Pack>False</Pack>
        <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
        <LastGenOutput>Test.txt</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    ...
</ItemGroup>
```